# Sublime Bracket Highlighter not coloring brackets

Tags: syntax-highlighting, sublimetext2, sublimetext

For me Bracket Highlighter plugin is not coloring and highlighting brackets but just underlining them in white.

Here is a snapshot:

[image: Sublime BracketHighlighter only underlines doesn't highlight]

Anyone knows of a solution?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Edit your `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/BracketHighlighter/bh_core.sublime-settings`

And set "style" to "highlight" for each bracket type you want highlighted.  Here is an example for curly brackets.

```
 // User defined region styles
 "curly": {
     "icon": "curly_bracket",
     "color": "entity.name.class",
     "style": "highlight"
 }
```

Comment: cool, I am able to highlight it, but now it highlights all of them with the same color, i.e. white even though I have set explicit colors for every type.

Comment: Like @lawlist mentioned, you need to set the colors in your `.tmTheme` file, and call those in your `bh_core.sublime-settings` file. (White is the BH2 default, I believe)

Comment: Hmm... this is really weird. coz on my other pc bracket highlighter works awesomely fine and I dint have to set anything up for it.

Comment: You can also use "solid" instead of "highlight".

Answer (score 31):

I have modified my example based upon the comments of `AGS` - it now includes a couple of highlight options and the rest are outline.  Thank you `AGS` and thank you to the original poster for creating this useful thread.

---

bh_core.sublime-settings

```
{
    "bracket_styles": {
        // This particular style is used to highlight
        // unmatched bracket pairs. It is a special
        // style.
        "unmatched": {
            "icon": "question",
            "color": "brackethighlighter.unmatched",
            "style": "highlight"
        },
        // User defined region styles
        "curly": {
            "icon": "curly_bracket",
            "color": "brackethighlighter.curly",
            "style": "highlight"
        },
        "round": {
            "icon": "round_bracket",
            "color": "brackethighlighter.round",
            "style": "outline"
        },
        "square": {
            "icon": "square_bracket",
            "color": "brackethighlighter.square",
            "style": "outline"
        },
        "angle": {
            "icon": "angle_bracket",
            "color": "brackethighlighter.angle",
            "style": "outline"
        },
        "tag": {
            "icon": "tag",
            "color": "brackethighlighter.tag",
            "style": "outline"
        },
        "single_quote": {
            "icon": "single_quote",
            "color": "brackethighlighter.quote",
            "style": "outline"
        },
        "double_quote": {
            "icon": "double_quote",
            "color": "brackethighlighter.quote",
            "style": "outline"
        },
        "regex": {
            "icon": "regex",
            "color": "brackethighlighter.quote",
            "style": "outline"
        }
    }
}
```

---

whatever_theme_file_you_use.tmTheme

```
<!-- BEGIN Bracket Highlighter plugin color modifications -->

<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Unmatched</string>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>brackethighlighter.unmatched</string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>foreground</key>
        <string>#FD971F</string>
    </dict>
</dict>

<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Bracket Curly</string>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>brackethighlighter.curly</string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>foreground</key>
        <string>#FF0000</string>
    </dict>
</dict>

<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Bracket Round</string>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>brackethighlighter.round</string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>foreground</key>
        <string>#0000FF</string>
    </dict>
</dict>

<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Bracket Square</string>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>brackethighlighter.square</string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>foreground</key>
        <string>#800080</string>
    </dict>
</dict>

<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Bracket Angle</string>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>brackethighlighter.angle</string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>foreground</key>
        <string>#AE81FF</string>
    </dict>
</dict>

<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Bracket Tag</string>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>brackethighlighter.tag</string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>foreground</key>
        <string>#FD971F</string>
    </dict>
</dict>

<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Single Quote | Double Quote | Regex</string>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>brackethighlighter.quote</string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>foreground</key>
        <string>#AE81FF</string>
    </dict>
</dict>

<!-- END Bracket Highlighter plugin color modifications -->
```

Comment: Search for the word `bracket` inside your theme file to see if there are conflicts with the settings listed above -- some themes come with bracket settings.  Also check to see if your syntax for the file is selected to something code-like.  For example, not much ever happens in plain old text mode.  Pick a color like red to do your tests so that you can really see if something is happening, and pick something simple like `[]` square brackets.  Try `outline` and also `highlight` just to see if the plugin is doing something.  My post is merely an excerpt of the ingredients necessary.

Comment: Tip: if you don't have a bh_core.sublime-settings file, create one using the content posted in this answer.

Answer (score 5):

Restart Sublime.

I just spent 20 mins hunting and trying all the above etc.  Finally found a comment elsewhere suggesting a restart; which fixed it and gave me a brief moment long enough to slap myself hard while it reloaded.