# Sublime Package: BracketHighlight - Django What's with all these underlines?

Tags: django, package, sublimetext

Why am I getting all these ugly white underlines? My python views file works just fine, no errors. What are these warnings? Is it because bracket highlight doesn't recognize django? Anyway to keep brackethighlight and get rid of the ugly underlines?

[image: views.py]

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sublime Bracket Highlighter not coloring brackets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15661731/sublime-bracket-highlighter-not-coloring-brackets)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well according to the [PEP8](http://pep8.readthedocs.org/en/latest/intro.html) and the problems I see, you have 3 problems:

```
1.- E122
```

> continuation line missing indentation or outdented

So you code have to look like this

```
reqProject = ProjectRequest(
           reqType = reqType,


2.- E251
```

> unexpected spaces around keyword / parameter equals

So you code have to look like this

```
reqProject = ProjectRequest(
           reqType=reqType,
```

And The last one is that you do not have a newline at end of file:

```
3.- W292
```

> no newline at end of file

And you can fix it adding a new line at the ond of file, also you can see the errors and the number and description of the error  in the status bar:

[image: Status bar and sorry for the image zoom :C]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhysa.png

Comment: Okay thank you. I'm new to a lot of the sublime packages and I guess I was too lazy to see how it all worked. Appreciate your response. I'd upvote but I just lost 2 reps asking this question lol