# How to enable brackethighlighter plugin in sublime text 3?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I am using sublime text 3 build 3059 , brackethighlighter plugin is installed but not working how to make it work ? i tried several solutions but no effect.
here is screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

The plugin is working - you'll notice in your screenshot that the opening and closing `{}` brackets are bold underlined in white (the default style), and are also shown in the gutter, next to the line numbers. If you want to customize the display more, first open `Preferences -> Package Settings -> Bracket Highlighter -> Bracket Settings - User`. It will be blank at first. Next, open `... -> Bracket Settings - Default`. Copy the entire contents of `Default` to `User`, then close `Default` (you can't edit it in Sublime Text 3).

Next, check out the [Bracket Highlighter Sublime Text 3 docs](https://github.com/facelessuser/BracketHighlighter/tree/BH2ST3) and read all about how to customize the plugin to your heart's content. Good luck!

Comment: i tried what you said. but i am getting colors on brackets. how can i set that ?

Comment: i have found a similar question but , i cant find theme file to edit here it is. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15661731/sublime-bracket-highlighter-not-coloring-brackets

Comment: Install [`PackageResourceViewer`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/PackageResourceViewer) from Package Control, then in the Command Palette choose `PackageResourceViewer: Open Resource`. All the default color schemes are in the `Color Scheme - Default` package, just scroll through the list to find the name of the theme you're using - it looks like Monokai or one of its derivatives. Edit the file according to the answer you referenced, then save it, and you should be all set.