# How can I enable additional (bracket-matching) functionality in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: sublimetext3

[image: Screenshot of bracket matching functionality. Sublime Text 3 is shown. Brackets are shown in the left sidebar, and matched brackets are highlighted in some HTML code to the right.]

I am new to Sublime Text 3 and I have found a screenshot showing some functionality I would like to enable - it shows some bracket matching capabilities.

How can I enable this functionality?

Comment: A quick Google of 'brackets sidebar Sublime Text 3' got me to this almost immediately - https://packagecontrol.io/packages/BracketHighlighter

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot you have included is of the ['BracketHighlighter' Package](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/BracketHighlighter).

To install a package, the recommended way is to [use Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io/installation) to do so.

(In the future, doing an internet search for the functionality you wish to enable, or a reverse-image search for the screenshot will probably help you find the answer faster.)

Answer (score -1):

compare these [example1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23314337/how-to-enable-brackethighlighter-plugin-in-sublime-text-3) [exapmles2](https://blog.generalassemb.ly/sublime-text-3-tips-tricks-shortcuts/)

this link may help you too
http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/extensibility/packages.html